# Battery not charging, Acer Aspire A515-54G

Tags: linux, drivers, battery

I have a problem with my laptop's battery, it's not charging. It all started since my laptop shut down because of low battery. I suppose that is the main reason. Anyway, I will describe what I did to try to solve this problem. This is the information I have about my battery status.
[image]

Well, the first thing I did to solve this problem was to disconnect the charger from my computer and press the power buttons for 30 sec. Then connect the charger to my computer and turn it on, but it didn't work, as you might imagine.
The second thing I did was to disconnect the battery from my laptop and turn it on, only with the charger, but that didn't work either.
In that sense, I have tested the voltage of the battery and the charger, and they are working at the same voltage specified on their specifications, they are 14,5v and 19,3v, respectively. I think the battery is still working, but in some way, it is not receiving energy from the charger.
Hope you can help me.

Comment: Can you try to operate your laptop from a live OS to see if by any chance there is an OS-related issue after all (though this is unlikely)?

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly a hardware problem.  It could be that the battery is not attached properly if you have a removable battery, or that the battery is defective or the connector is broken, or something else entirely.

Usually charging isn't controlled by the OS because you want it to happen even if the computer is off or the OS has a problem.  There are sometimes ways that the OS can influence it, but usually not to the extent that the battery won't charge.  Presumably you'd see the same lack of charging if the computer were powered off, in which case you'd clearly know that your OS was not the problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, this problem is really rare, I have notice that somehow the battery is discharging.